# How can I record a window using ffmpeg by id?

Tags: qt, c++11, ffmpeg, qml

I want to get the id of the window by name using c++ or qml and record the specific screen using this id in ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -wid 0x6200012 -s 1920x1052 -r 30 -i :0.0+0,0
```

How can I do this?

it's not necessary to be the id, can be the offset-x and offset-y, I just want to record the window in any position.

Comment: Can't test but `ffmpeg -f x11grab -x 200 -y 100 -video_size 1920x1052 -framerate 30 -i :0.0+0,0` should work.

Comment: I think that this doesn't work for me, because the flag -i :0.0+0,0 start grabbing of the position x=0 and y=0 of the screen, I want record the screen in any position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see that [x11grab](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab) can record some screen by id as [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1378465) indicates so as that answer points out one option is to use GStreamer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc xid=0x04000007 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

How do I get the window id in Qt?

- If QQmlApplicationEngine is used with Window or ApplicationWindow:

  ```cpp
  #include <QGuiApplication>
  #include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
  #include <QWindow>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

      QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

      QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
      const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
      QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                       &app, [url, &engine](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
          if (!obj && url == objUrl)
              QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
          if(QWindow *w = qobject_cast<QWindow *>(engine.rootObjects().first())){
              qDebug() << w->winId();
          }
      }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
      engine.load(url);

      return app.exec();
  }
  ```
- With QQuickView

  ```
  #include <QGuiApplication>
  #include <QQuickView>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

      QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

      QQuickView view;

      const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
      view.setSource(url);
      view.show();
      qDebug() << view.winId();
      return app.exec();
  }
  ```
- Qt Widgets:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    qDebug() << w.winId();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Or in general you should access the QWindow and get the window id:

```
for(QWindow *w : QGuiApplication::allWindows()){
    qDebug() << w->winId();
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do the same with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2):

I found out the following:

```
ffmpeg -y -s 800x600 -f x11grab -window_id 0x3200008 -framerate 30 -i :11.0+0,0 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 40 output_select_window.mp4
```

Very important explanation:

```
-window_id = 'xwininfo' shows window_id if you select a window
```

```
-i :11.0+0,0 = 11 means and from in shell with `$echo $Display`.
```

Comment: I get: `Unrecognized option 'window_id'`

Comment: Can you show the full command line? You need to find out window_id.

Comment: exactly the same as you posted, but the id replaced by that of an existing window. I have ffmpeg 5.1.3. It turned out to depend on the build configuration. It might have been `--disable-xlib` vs `--enable-xlib`, I'm not sure anymore. With Nix, one needs to use `ffmpeg-full` instead of `ffmpeg`.